# String.prototype.replace won't replace a &times character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

The HTML part I'm fetching with jQuery is:

```
         <div class="chip">
              #<c:out value="${pred.id } "></c:out><span class="closebtn">&times;</span>
          </div>
```

I use this jQuery to fetch the elements with class "chip":

```
function getChips() {
      var output = "";
      $('.chip').each(function() {
          output += $(this).text().trim();
      });
      output = output.replace(/U00D7/gi," ");
      return output;
  }
```

So, it does fetch the correct elements. So far so good. And function above returns the inner text of each element of class "chip".

But it does not replace the "times" character that can be seen in the html fragment above. I tried:

`output = output.replace(/U00D7/gi," ");`

and I tried:

`output = output.replace(/&times/gi," ");`

and even being desperate and trying:

`output = output.replace(/x/gi," ");`

and:

`output = output.replace(/X/gi," ");`

Still get an output from the function with &times symbols in it. I expect a string with &times symbols replaced with a space or even better, nothing at all -> "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the character entity by its unicode reference your regex needs to be `\u00D7`, not `U00D7`.

Also note that the logic can be made more succinct by using `map()`. Try this:

```js
function getChips() {
  return $('.chip').map(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim();
  }).get().join('').replace(/\u00D7/gi, " ");
}

console.log(getChips());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chip">
  <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>
  Lorem
</div>
<div class="chip">
  <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>
  Ipsum
</div>
<div class="chip">
  <span class="closebtn">&times;</span>
  Dolor
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks dude! u tha Boss! :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Note that I just updated the answer; calling `replace()` inside the loop is a bit wasteful so I moved it outside.